# Parsing data into access from network shared excel workbook

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am parsing a worksheet into Access using the following code:

```
    Sub LoadRates(ByRef TimesheetFile As Excel.Workbook)

       On Error GoTo LoadDataCollection_Error

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim LastRow As Integer

        Dim shRates As Excel.Worksheet
        Set shRates = TimesheetFile.Worksheets("Rates")

        shRates.ShowAllData
        LastRow = shRates.Cells(shRates.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        shRates.Cells(1, 4).value = "Current"                

        Dim db As DAO.Database
        Set db = CurrentDb

        Dim strSQL As String

        Dim dbWb As String
        dbWb = "[Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;Database=" & TimesheetFile.FullName & "].[Rates$A1:i" & LastRow & "]"


        strSQL = "SELECT A.[Entity no] AS Entity,Staff AS Name, A.Current as Rates, Company, [2015 BCTC category] AS BCTC_Category,[2015 Rating] As Rating " & _
             " INTO fromTimesheet " & _
             " FROM " & dbWb & " AS A "



        db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

       Exit Sub


    LoadDataCollection_Error:
        ... do stuff...
    End Sub
```

my problem is that I have to change the column 4's header to "Current" manually because the title is currently a date value, thus inappropriate for SQL to pick up

```
        shRates.Cells(1, 4).value = "Current"
```

when I execute this code. sometimes it returns an error message saying it cannot find the field A.Current , and other times it would be able to find it. Is this caused by the workbook being set to Shared?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Upon testing, I found out that this error has to do with the excel workbook being "Shared". Once I made the workbook exclusive, the code was able to pick up me editing the row value.

This leads me to believe that when I instantiate an excel workbook object that is being shared. It should be treated as read-only.

Hopefully this is helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your column header is not being effectively saved and connection is using last saved instance.

Consider manually saving it after you make your change. Also, be sure you have write access to save workbook and not in shared/read-only (or alternatively save a different temp workbook for import):

```
shRates.Cells(1, 4).value = "Current"
TimesheetFile.Save
```

But also consider using [DoCmd.TransferSpreadshet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793.aspx) method instead of worksheet connection (which can facilitate "shared" process). Usually one uses a true database for connection and not flatfiles like spreadsheets.

```
Sub LoadRates(ByRef TimesheetFile As Excel.Workbook)
On Error GoTo LoadDataCollection_Error

    Dim i As Integer, LastRow As Integer
    Dim shRates As Excel.Worksheet

    Set shRates = TimesheetFile.Worksheets("Rates")

    shRates.ShowAllData
    LastRow = shRates.Cells(shRates.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    shRates.Cells(1, 4).value = "Current" 
    TimesheetFile.Close True     ' SAVES AND CLOSES

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, "fromTimesheet", _
                              TimesheetFile.FullName, True, "Rates!"

    Exit Sub

LoadDataCollection_Error:
    ... do stuff...

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for introducing me to this transferSpreadsheet method. what would be the advantage of using this rather than worksheet connection? I notice it does not let me choose my fields , but on the other hand i wouldn't need to indicate the lastRow any more.

Comment: No DAO database object to define/use/uninitialize, fewer CPU resources as no connection holds in memory, database and application abstraction as Excel is only used as end use document, less room for file corruption or security hazards, etc.